# Anyone using Memcached with ASP.NET on a distributed farm?

Tags: asp.net, memcached

We have 22 HTTP servers each running their own individual ASP.NET Caches. They read from a read only DB that is only updated off peak hours.

We use a file dependency to invalidate the cache, prompting the servers to "new up" their caches...If this is accidentally done during peak hours, it risks bringing down our DB cluster due to the sudden deluge of open connections.

Has anyone used memcached with ASP.NET in this distributed form? It seems to me that it would offer a huge advantage of having to only build up one cache (and hit the DB 21 times less), while memcached would handle distributing it on each box.

If you have, do you place it on the same box as the HTTP boxes, or do you run a separate cache tier? How well does it scale, can we expect it to need powerful servers? Our working dataset is not huge (We fit it into 4 gigs of memory on each HTTP box just fine).

How do you handle invalidation?

Looking for experiences and war stories.

EDIT: Win2k3, IIS6, 64-bit servers...4 gigs per box (I believe, we may have upped it to 16 gigs when we changed to 64-bit servers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "memcached would handle distributing it on each box"

memcached does not distribute or replicate a cache to each box in a memcached farm.  The memcached client basically hashes the key and chooses a cache server based on that hash.  When one of the memcached servers fail you will lose whatever cached items existed on that server, however, the client will recognize the failure and begin writing values to a different server.  This being the case, your code needs to account for missing items in the cache and reset them if necessary.

This article discusses the memcached architecture in more detail: [How memcached works](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#How_does_memcached_work?).

Comment: Thanks, I just spent an hour reading everything on that site.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice (according to the memcached site) is to run memcached on the same box as your web server app or else you're making http calls (which isn't all that bad, but it's not optimal). If you're running a 64-bit app server (which you probably should if you're going to be running memcached), then you can load up each of the servers with loads of memory and it will be available to memcached. There's not much in the way of CPU resources used by memcached, so if your current app server isn't very taxed, it will remain that way.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used them together, but I've used them both on separate projects.

Last I saw the documentation explicitly said that sharing with the web server was ok.

Memcache really only needs RAM and if you take your asp.net cache out of the equation how much RAM is you web server actually using? Probably not much. It won't compete much with your web server for CPU and it doesn't need disk at all. You might consider segmenting off the network traffic (if you don't already) from the incoming web requests.

It worked well and was fast I didn't have any problems with it.

Oh, invalidation was explicit on the project I used it on. Not sure what other modes there are for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get replication accross your memcached servers then it maybe worth a look at [repcached](http://repcached.lab.klab.org/). It's a patch for memcached that handles the replication part.

Answer (score 0):

Worth checking out [Velocity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc655792.aspx), which is a distributed cache provided by Microsoft. I cannot give you a point-by-point comparison to memcached, but Velocity is integrated with ASP.NET and will continue to get more development and integration.